# Chart transition maps in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, terminology, observers

To my understanding, Lorentz transformations are the chart transition maps between charts of different observers, but what would be the name of chart transition maps of a single observer? Naturally he can describe the space time he observes using many different types of $(x,t)$ coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

> Lorentz transformations are the chart transition maps between charts of different observers

That is incorrect. As you mentioned, the same observer can use many different charts. For example, one could use polar coordinates, in which case Lorentz transformations won't be the chart transition maps. Also, one could pick a non-inertial observer. A more appropriate statement would be that Poincaré transformations are the chart transition maps between Cartesian charts associated to inertial observers, where by "Poincaré transformation" I mean a Lorentz transformation followed by a spacetime translation.

Notice this time I did not impose the observers to be different: a Lorentz transformation also relates different charts attributable to the same observer. Namely, spatial axis rotations, for example.

> But what would be the name of chart transition maps of a single observer?

If you're restricting the charts to Cartesian charts (i.e., if you're imposing the metric components to be $\mathrm{diag}(-1, +1, +1, +1)$), then they are still Poincaré transformations, where I'm admitting that the same observer could use charts with different origins in spacetime (if you want to exclude that, they are just Lorentz transformations). If you want to allow more general charts (spherical coordinates, cylindrical, coordinates, arbitrary coordinates), there is no general name. It is simply a general coordinate transformation (in the Physics language) or a diffeomorphism (in the more mathematical language), as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: So, what are the general chart transition map which preserve the space time metric? Are we forced to work in cartesian ? o_o [I am referring to first paragraph] offtopic:  I must say you look quite dashing in the photo

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai All chart transition maps preserve the metric, they just don't preserve the metric components. If you want the metric components to be $(-1,+1,+1,+1)$, then you do have to work in Cartesian coordinates and the transformations are Poincaré transformations. Most textbooks dealing with special, but not general, relativity choose to restrict their attention to Cartesian coordinates. That is also pretty much the only reason Lorentz transformations are seem as so important. Other treatments often end up mentioning them as almost a mere curiosity. Thanks for the compliment hahah

Comment: I finally came back to this and I am confused. Here ". As you mentioned, the same observer can use many different charts. For example, one could use polar coordinates, in which case Lorentz transformations won't be the chart transition maps.", but I said that it's between diff observer not same.

Comment: "Notice this time I did not impose the observers to be different: a Lorentz transformation also relates different charts attributable to the same observer. Namely, spatial axis rotations, for example." Could you explain spatial axis rotations

Comment: Finally what are cartesian charts and polar charts? Is it possible to give a mathematical definition?

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai The same argument also holds for different observers. One of them might use Cartesian coordinates (i.e., time and Cartesian coordinates on the spatial axes) while the other uses spherical (time and spherical coordinates on the spatial axes), which I previously called polar. The chart transition maps won't be Lorentz transformations

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai spatial axes rotations are simply rotating the spatial axes. For example, the same observer might choose different directions for what they call the $x$ axis. These different choices are related by rotations, which are a particular case of Lorentz transformations

Answer (score 0):

That would just be a general coordinate transformation or (in more strict mathematical language) a diffeomorphism.

\begin{equation}
g'^{\mu \nu} = g^{\alpha \beta} \frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} \, \frac{\partial x'^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

In special relativity an inertial observer fixes a time coordinate and the origin in minkowski coordinates. You could say each inertial observer is described by an equivaence class of minkowski coordinates where the equivelnce relation is spatial rotations.